# Convert bool to int and int to bool

Tags: python, beginner, converting

I'm a noob.

I wrote this code to convert bools to ints and ints to bools as a past-time but I would like to know whether to continue programming - this is the kind of thing I've been doing, no useful scripts at all.

So, I wanted a program and not a module and that's why I wrote the decorator `tab`: for output. "|" means it's called from the outer scope, and "    |" means it's one function deep. boolxint, bool to int. intxbool, int to bool. I also did not want to dirty the functions with prints.

I thought it'd be OK to name the decorator underscore, because it just doesn't show.

`boolean` returns an int and `integer` takes an int and returns a bool. It plays on bool being a subclass of int and plays only with 0's and 1's, False's and True's. Think bool.real, think indexes...

```
__author__ = 'joao pedro'


def tab(s):
    def _(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(s)

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return _


@tab('    | boolxint')
def boolean(index: bool) -> int:
    return [0, 1][index]


@tab('    | intxbool')
def integer(index: int) -> bool:
    return [False, True][index]


@tab('|')
def convert(index):
    if type(index) is bool:
        return boolean(index)

    if type(index) is int:
        return integer(index)


print(convert(False))
print(convert(True))
print(convert(0))
print(convert(1))
```

This is what it does

```
|
    | boolxint
0
|
    | boolxint
1
|
    | intxbool
False
|
    | intxbool
True
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(convert(-1))` and/or `print(convert(-2))`?  Did you expect that output?  How about `x = convert(0)` without any print in sight?  Did you really need it to generate output to the console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Don't overengineer things: it leads to code bloat**. As you know, `bool` is
already a subclass of `int`, so conversion between the two should be really
simple. You end up having your primary `convert()` function, two helpers that
use index-based trickeration, and then an entire decorator apparatus to print
stuff telling you which helper was called. For comparison, here's a simpler
approach, with and without validation. Because everything is in one function, I
feel no desire for a decorator to tell me which helper was called.

```
def convert(x):
    # Quick and dirty.
    return int(x) if x in (True, False) else bool(x)

def convert(x):
    # With validation.
    if x in (True, False):
        return int(x)
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        return bool(x)
    else:
        raise ValueError('...')
```

**Overengineering often leads to bugs or ill-conceived design**. Due to its
index-based mechanics your code doesn't deliver on its promised ability to
convert int to bool: it blows up when given anything other than `0` or `1` [correction: as noted in a comment from AJNeufeld, the
code also accepts `-1` and `-2`, but gives undesirable answers]. In
fairness, you say that the code was written with that intent. But
the world doesn't need an int-to-bool converter that handles only zeros and
ones ... because `False` and `True` are already interchangeable with `0` and
`1`. If your converter won't handle all integers, what good is it?
And if you truly want to limit the conversions to such a small universe
of inputs, why write a function at all when a dict will do the same thing?

```
convert = {0: False, 1: True, False: 0, True: 1}

convert[True] # If you squint, it almost looks like calling a function.
```

**Should you continue with programming**? Absolutely! In my experience, it has
usually been interesting, sometimes fun, and always useful in career,
academics, and
personal projects. Every new
programmer comes up with strange, convoluted ideas. Don't let this early detour discourage you.

Comment: You've overengineered this yourself!  `bool(x)` by itself will suffice, even if `x` is already `True` or `False`.

Comment: Anyone needing bool-to-int conversion (for example, sending a JSON payload to a receiving web service with stringent type requirements), would not be satisfied with an everything-to-bool converter.

Comment: Well if you actually need `int` then `int(bool(x))` will work too.

Comment: @MarkRansom You are ignoring the the OP's stated goal: convert to the *other* type. Granted, it's a dubious goal. But your proposed alternatives -- everything to bool or everything to int -- are beside the point.

Comment: The question was poorly written, it wasn't clear that ping-ponging between types was the goal.

Comment: @MarkRansom First you say I overengineered. Then you say the OP has written poorly. But the OP's second sentence starts with "I wrote this code to convert bools to ints and ints to bools" and the OP's code demo clearly illustrates the behavior of `convert()`. Perhaps this was a case of hasty reading? I've certainly been guilty of that a few times on StackOverflow, CodeReview, etc. IMO, the best outcome for you in this case is for this entire comment conversation to be deleted. I'll follow your lead.

Comment: OK, you're right - I didn't understand the question, not because it's poorly written but because it's nonsensical.  Usually people want a consistent result.  You were also right about something else - overengineering leads to bugs.  Did you try the code you posted?  Neither snippet works correctly, because `0` and `False` are interchangeable as are `1` and `True`.